# Microsoft Access percentage of subtotal

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to run the following query below to get the country weight for each fund. The trouble is you can't use Over/Partition for it. Thanks in advance

[image: Source Data]

[image: Example outcome]

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select fund, country, 
    1.0 * sum(marketvalue) 
        / (select sum(t1.marketvalue) from mytable as t1 where t1.fund = t.fund) 
        as country_percent
from mytable as t
```

Answer (score 0):

This is two levels of aggregation -- at the country/fund level and the fund level.  One method is:

```
select cf.*, cf.value * 1.0 / f.value
from (select country, fund, sum(value) as value
      from t
      group by country, fund
     ) as cf inner join
     (select fund, sum(value) as value
      from t
      group by fund
     ) as f
     on f.fund = cf.fund;
```